# Is it possible to Update a certain column value and Delete it with 2 different table?

Tags: mysql, datagridview, mysql-workbench, vb.net-2010

```
  For k As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    Dim Query1 As String
                    Query1 = "Update librarydb.blist SET quantity=(quantity + 1) where quantity = '" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(k).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'"
                    command1 = New MySqlCommand(Query1, MysqlConn1)
                    SDA1.SelectCommand = command1
                    SDA1.Fill(dbDataSet1)
                    bSource1.DataSource = dbDataSet1
                    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource1
                    SDA1.Update(dbDataSet1)
                    Dim Query2 As String
                    For j As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                        Query2 = "delete from returnlist where student_id= '" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(j).Cells(1).Value.ToString & "'"
                        command1 = New MySqlCommand(Query1, MysqlConn1)
                        SDA1.SelectCommand = command1
                        SDA1.Fill(dbDataSet1)
                        bSource1.DataSource = dbDataSet1
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource1
                        SDA1.Update(dbDataSet1)
                    Next
                Next
```

What i am trying to do is in the first query it will update in the blist table in column 0. And in the 2nd query it will delete the selected row in returnlist Table.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute as many queries as you want. You put together your query string like that:

```
"UPDATE tableA set fieldA = value; " +
"DELETE tableB WHERE fieldB = value"
```

So you can put multiple queries and execute them, put you need to separate them with a semi-colon.

So you could put together your 2 queries into one query variable:

```
Dim Query As String
Query = "delete from returnlist where quantity= '" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(k).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'; " &
"delete from returnlist where quantity= '" & Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(k).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'"
```

Then you can execute both commands together.

Comment: Sir it would be great if you can give me a deeper example. Thank you

Comment: Mysql Systax erroir near 28 at line 1.

Comment: 28 is the integer value of quantity

Comment: Ive tried to use a single query and only use the update query but still the update query doesnt work.

Comment: hmm not sure what the error is. Can you run the query directly in mysql workbench or similar tool?

Comment: So you want me to run an update query to Mysql workbench?